# sync a Palm Pre on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, palm-pre

I just upgraded to a **Palm Pre** from a **Centro**.  Before doing so, I synced my Centro with **jpilot** on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine (as I had been doing all along).

Can I now just sync the new Pre with jpilot to get all my data onto it?  I want to ask before I try it in case there are some known gotchas that I should be warned of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Tom... I have since discovered [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/) and this [blog post](http://blog.treonauts.com/2009/06/palm-pre-sync-solutions.html) which gives more info about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, here's the thing about the Palm Pre: you're not supposed to ever have to sync it yourself, regardless of the system.

Palm put a lot of effort into their Synergy solution, which grabs your calendar data from Google Calendar and your contacts from your email accounts and facebook. Hotsyncing is no longer supported, and there is no bundled software for automatic syncing between computer and Pre directly.

If you just want to transfer images, music, or documents onto your Pre, you can connect it as a USB drive using the included USB cable; your computer should recognize it as a thumbdrive if you select the appropriate option on your Pre.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way - Palm's [Data Transfer Assistant](http://www.palm.com/us/support/downloads/pre/migration/dta_windows.html):

> The Data Transfer Assistant (DTA) provides a one-time, one-way export of data from Palm Desktop or standalone Outlook to your phone, moving your data to an online service in the process. Your phone syncs with the online service.

But it's Windows-only.